# matplotlib axis redraw on zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a simple graph with a Navigation Tool Bar. When I zoom or pan, the graph is correctly updated, but the axis labels get messed up. Its as if it does not clear the old text out before drawing the new text. So you see the new text written over the old. If I resize the window, it seems to do a full re-draw and fixes the labels. Here is my simple example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from Tix import *
from Tkconstants import *

root = Tk()
f = Figure(figsize=(12,5), dpi=100, frameon=False)
s = f.add_subplot(111, title="test")
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,2,6,7,3,6]

s.plot(x,y,label="Test")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)


root.mainloop()
```

Here is a before:
[image]

Here is after panning:
[image]

Comment: I assume you are embedding this in another program and can't use `pyplot`?  It might be worth digging in to how the `TkAgg` `FigureManager` deals with this  [see this code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py#L509).

Comment: I see “tix” in those screenshots; yikes! Does anyone know of anyone who actually actively maintains Tix? (The last substantial changes I see in the repo on SourceForge are from 4 years ago…)

Comment: Not relevant, it had the same issue in in tk/tkinter. I used it because I wanted to use the Notebook widget in my project.

Comment: The frameon=False option may be the culprit. Have you tried it without?

Comment: That was it! took frameon out and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Oblivion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635557/oblivion):
Removing the `frameon=False` option from `f = Figure(figsize=(12,5), dpi=100, frameon=False)` solved the issue.